Murderer in Christie's The Adventure of the Egyptian Tomb
Spoiler alert: this question reveals the murderer. Please do not add spoiler markup; see the ongoing discussion on Meta.
From his reactions after he was called into Poirot's tent for help, we can deduce that Dr. Ames was behind all the deaths but one. However, the following paragraphs are a bit confusing.

“We can now sleep in peace,” he declared happily. “And I can do with some sleep. My head, it aches abominably. Ah, for a good tisane!”
As though in answer to prayer, the flap of the tent was lifted and Hassan appeared, bearing a steaming cup which he offered to Poirot. It proved to be camomile tea, a beverage of which he is inordinately fond. Having thanked Hassan and refused his offer of another cup for myself, we were left alone once more. I stood at the door of the tent some time after undressing, looking out over the desert.
 Christie, Agatha. "The Adventure of the Egyptian Tomb." 1923. Poirot Investigates. New Bantam Edition. New York: Bantam, 1970, 6th printing 1978. pp. 75–89. Quote is from p. 86.

The story doesn't state explicitly who prepared the tea, only that it was delivered by Hassan. If Dr. Ames could've kept his cool as he did in the earlier "Anubis" hoax, Poirot might not have been able to pin the charges on him.
On another hand, if Dr. Ames had added a thing or two into the tea, how could Hassan not find out (since they don't seem to live in the same tent)? Looks like he was the one preparing the tea for the detective?

You are correct, this is an unexplained detail. However, there are several likely explanations. It is true that Hassan is John Willard's, and subsequently Guy Willard's, servant, but he seems to be at the disposal of anybody on the team—for example, he dresses up as Anubis when Poirot asks him to (p. 89), despite the fact that the latter has only just arrived. So Dr Ames could have made the tea himself and asked Hassan to deliver it. Alternatively, he could have gone into the kitchen as Hassan was making the tea and asked him to fetch something from one of the other tents, using his absence to add the poison. So while we do not know exactly how it is that Dr Ames was able to poison the beverage without Hassan's knowledge, this is not so much a plot hole as a loose end.
It is interesting to speculate on Hassan's role in the expedition generally, though. He describes himself specifically as the Willards' servant (p. 85), but seems to be at the beck and call of the entire team. Since Christie had been on archæological expeditions to Egypt, I assume she is drawing on personal experience in depicting it as normal for native servants to be ordered about by any white person, even when nominally in the employ of a particular individual.

Thanks for your detailed explanation, verbose. You are quite right in that this might have been drawn from Christie's own experience in Egypt.

Hassan's role when not on archeological dig is that of Willard's servant. When on an archeological dig, his role is that of a gopher and "chief servant" of all the other physical laborers. You could order in English any of the natives but the chances of them understanding the order correctly are dodgy. Or you could order Hassan and he would translate your order to them. Or just do it himself, whatever is more expedient.
